# Google Analytics (Internet Marketing - Tracking website - Query Parameter)

Tags: google-analytics

If there is no query parameter in the url of search bar results and I want to track inside google analytics what guests search inside Search bar on my website then I need to add the following code inside the GA tracking code:

```
pageTracker._trackPageview("/searchresults.html?q=$keyword");
```

but how to translate it into new version of tracking code? with `gaq` word.

Also whoever would be willing  to answer please say if I have to change `$keyword` or `keyword` with anything else or can I type EXACTLY this?

Also please say where exactly, inside google analytics tracking code, do I need to paste the code line? Probably somewhere around word `var` but don't know where...

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview','/searchresults.html?q=$keyword']);
```

it can be anywhere in your page, it should replace the default

> _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

call

You will need to have server side code (PHP, ASP, ...) fill in the value for $keyword.

Next, you will need to enable search term parsing in your GA Profile(s) settings.

Beware to use a parameter name ('q' here) that isn't used for other purpose in your site, elese every URL logged to GA and containing this parameter will be parsed as search query and the value will be considered as a keyword.